# Get notified when some other app tries to open the activity using custom action

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting an Activity from other application using the following custom action :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("some.custom.action.ACTION");
 startActivity(intent)
```

and i am able to start the activity, i have registered the same action in menifest of my application as below :

```
<activity
   android:name=".TestActivity"
   android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="some.custom.action.ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

now the problem is when my (TestActivity) activity is running i am not able to start it again using same method. I need to restart that activity(TestActivity) again when other application tries to start my activity(TestActivity).

i tried `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but it is not doing the trick.

i am getting the following warning:

```
Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance
```

but i am not sure how to get this intent in my app.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i resolved this by adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in activity tag and adding flag in intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

after that i got new intent in

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){}
```

final Activity tag:

```
 <activity
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:name=".TestActivity"
   android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="some.custom.action.ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

final intent :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("some.custom.action.ACTION");
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
 startActivity(intent)
```